# I am trying to convert a python .PY file to .EXE. But the EXE file won't run because of "Fatal Error Detected Failed To Execute Script Error" Help Pls

Tags: pyinstaller

I am a absolute beginner with Python. What I have done so far is I have installed Python with IDLE, Pycharm, Pygame-zero and Pyinstaller too. I have a (.py) file game I would like to turn into a (.exe) file. So I can release my game for my friends to play.

I have entered this command into CMD window "pyinstaller --onefile -w gamename.py"* (*My game is not really called "gamename". I have called it that in this code above. For this example only.)

When in the file folder of my game and then Pyinstaller converts my file into the (.exe) file. But everytime I try to run this file. It fails with this error message - "Fatal Error Detected, Failed To Execute Script Error".

I have watched all kinds of YouTube videos trying to solve this problem and have tried these following fixes:

1. Updated Pyinstaller (4.3).
2. Updated Python (3.9.5).
3. Changed the path in Enviroment Variables to point to Python39\Scripts and resetting my computer.
4. Coverted the (.py) file to (.exe) by including the console window. Then after running the program after when the console window disappears. Opening the CMD window again and typing the file directly "gamename.exe" to run.
5. Installing auto-py-to-exe program.
6. Each time deleting the Main, Dis and Spec files and moving the (.exe) file into the main file folder. With the resources for the games. Music, Images and Sounds.
7. Testing out my Python script to check. If it doesn't have any errors while loading through IDLE and it doesn't. It works straight away, I can play my game through IDLE. There is no errors in the code of my game script.

And after trying all of these solutions it still hasn't solved this issue.I still have the same error message appearing when trying to run my game. Now I have found out what the meaning is to this error message that appears. Which is:

"Fatal Error: failed to execute

This means something has gone wrong as it's giving you a visual warning about it; this is not an error, it's a warning; the real error has been printed to stdout/stderr. If you open the executable using the terminal or something else that will preserve the console output, you will most likely see a Python error telling you what went wrong. Fixing this and repackaging is the solution to this issue".

I have remade the (.exe) file including the console window and it does explan what the error is. When I try to run my game, the error comes up as:

"FileNotFoundError: {Errno 2} No such file or directory: C:*****\Local\Temp_MEI58602\pgzero\data\icon.png {4268} Failed to execute script.

Any suggestions? On how to fix this error please. So I can run and play my game outside of Python on any PC.

A Possible Answer:

I have found a webpage that has the possible answer to my problem. But I don't know what they mean, because I am a beginner with Python. Can anybody read this and break it down for me? Here is what it say's:

"Pyinstaller packaging exe, missing icons and other issues

1. Reason

When the exe runs, it will decompress a resource folder named "_MEI*" to a temporary directory on the computer, and delete it when the program ends.

uses a path like ‘\icon.png’ in the program. When the exe is running, it will only search for its own directory, of course it cannot be found.

Two, the solution

1. Make sure the picture is in this temporary resource folder

This can be done by editing the'.spec' configuration file to add pictures.

(Note: .spec is the file generated by Pyinstaller last time, in your python project directory.)

These are the three pictures I used, which is actually adding three tuples to the "binaries" list

Before the comma is the address of the picture in the python project, after the comma is the address of the package into the ‘_MEI*’ temporary folder.

I have built an ‘img’ folder to store pictures in it. Just put a dot in the root directory, such as (’./img/info.png’,’.’)

Finally, run when packagingpyinstaller program entry.spec, You can add the picture resource.

(Note: Other external resources can also be added in this way, such as .ini, .txt, .exe, etc.)

2. Make sure the program can find this path

Because the name of the temporary directory is different each time, a method is needed to dynamically obtain this path.

The code is presented, and the core statement is ‘os.path.realpath(sys.path[0])’.

Python running effect is as follows:

Package it as an exe, drag it to the cmd window and run it."

Here is the link to the webpage to the article. Because it makes use of screenshots that I can't include on this webpage;

(https://www.programmersought.com/article/94965073850/)

Please read this acticle and break it down for me. It does seem to be explaining the solution to my problem. But what does it all mean? What pictures is he talking about? Please explain.

Comment: Read the documentation about adding data files to the bundle https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/spec-files.html#adding-files-to-the-bundle and the documentation about how to find files at runtime in a onefile exe https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/runtime-information.html#placing-data-files-at-expected-locations-inside-the-bundle - you probably need to use the guidance in the documentation about how your code can establish if it is running frozen, to locate files - see https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/runtime-information.html#using-sys-executable-and-sys-argv-0

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why but *PyInstaller* doesn't seem to bundle everything needed for *Pygame Zero*, including that `icon.png` file. The solution is simple, though. You just need to use `pyinstaller --collect-all pgzero --onefile -w <scipt_name>`. If your game has sounds, images or anything like that, remember to include those specific folders as well using `--add-data <file_or_folder>`. Also, make sure your script includes the following lines.

```py
import pgzrun

# GAME CODE HERE

pgzrun.go()
```

I hope it helps, even though it is a little late.